# How to link up web api call to the list view

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have my dart call to my api get method. Btw the way am just learning flutter and dart and trying out basic crud operations I would use to be doing in .net and c#

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:theapp/models/Players.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

  class ApiService {
    final String apiUrl = "https://apiurlhidden.com/api";
    final String getAllPlayersEndPoint = "/GetAllPlayers/";

    Future<List<Player>> getAllPlayers() async {
      final getallPlayersUrl = Uri.parse(apiUrl + getAllPlayersEndPoint);

      Response res = await get(getallPlayersUrl);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);
        List<Player> players =
            body.map((dynamic item) => Player.fromJson(item)).toList();
        return players;
      } else {
        throw "Failed to load cases list";
      }
    }
  }
```

And I have my listview here but it complaining saying key and players do not exist

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:theapp/models/Players.dart';

class PlayerList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Player> players = [];

  PlayerList({Key key, this.players}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: players == null ? 0 : players.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
              child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text(players[index].firstName),
              subtitle: Text(players[index].surname.toString()),
            ),
          ));
        });
  }
}
```

My Model
class Player {
final int id;
final int type;
final String playerLevel;
final String firstName;
final String surname;

```
  Player(this.id, this.type, this.playerLevel, this.firstName, this.surname);

  factory Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Player(
      json['id'],
      json['type'],
      json['playerlevel'],
      json['firstname'],
      json['surname'],
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Players{id: $id, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $surname}';
}
```

Is there any reason why it should not recognize players and key in my list view page also how do I get the items to appear in the listview.

Picture only added to show the context in the items I mentioned above. Also coming from a .net background I would normally use an observable collection so it gets any changes in data in real-time am I using the correct approach for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `required` keyword to make parameters mandatory.

```
PlayerList({required Key key, required this.players}) : super(key: key);
```

> Named parameters are optional unless they’re explicitly marked as required.

See [Parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters) for details.